Let $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ so that $P(0) = 0$ and $P(X+1) - P(X-1) = X^2 + X$. Find the value of $P(\frac{3}{2})$.

Let $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ so that $P(0) = 0$ and $P(X+1) - P(X-1) = X^2 + X$. Find the value of $P(\frac{3}{2})$.

My first attempt was to substitute X for $1$, which lead me to $P(2) - P(0) = 2$, so $P(2) = 2$. Similarly, I can find the values of $P(4), P(6),$ and so on by substituting X with an odd number. However that doesn't seem to help.
I have also tried substituting $X \to X + \frac{1}{2}$, which leads to: $P(X + \frac{3}{2}) - P(X - \frac{1}{2}) = X^2 + 2X + \frac{3}{4}$, and substituting X for $0$,
$P(\frac{3}{2}) = P(-\frac{1}{2}) + \frac{3}{4}$.
I think there's definitely something I'm missing!

$P$ a polynomial here?

@BoweiTang yes!! sorry for the confusion.

Hint: Assume $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx$ and use $P(x+2)-P(x)=x^2+3x+2=a(x+2)^3+b(x+2)^2+c(x+2)-(ax^3+bx^2+cx)$ to get $a,b,c$.
Edit: If $P(x)=dx^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx$, then the expanded form is $8dx^3+\ldots$, you'll get $d=0$.

The expanded form is $6ax^2+12ax+4bx+8a+4b+2c$ from Wolfram.

Why can we 'assume' that $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $3$? And besides, from the expanded form, there is no solution of $(a,b,c)$

@NN2 $(1/6,1/4,-1/6)$

Alternativily we can directly calculate $P(2k)$, as you observed.
As $P(2(k+1))-P(2k) = (2k+1)(2k+2)$ we can sum the left and right side and get a telescoping sum:
$$
P(2k) = \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} P(2(m+1))-P(2m) = \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} (2m+1)(2m+2) = \frac{4}{3} k^3 + k^2 - \frac{1}{3}k 
$$
The first equality is due to the telescopic nature of the sum, the last equality follows by calculating the sum using the sum of consecutive integers and consecutive squares formulas.
Defining $g(x) = \frac{4}{3} (x/2)^3 + (x/2)^2 - \frac{1}{3}(x/2) =\frac{1}{12} \left( 2x^3 + 3x^2 - 2x \right)$. We find that $g$ and $P$ match on the set of even integers. As they are both polynomials $g(x) - P(x)$ is a polynomial with infinite zeros, so it is the zero polynomial, therefore:
$$
\boxed{
P(x) = g(x) = \frac{1}{12} \left( 2x^3 + 3x^2 - 2x \right)
}
$$

This is so smart!! Thank you!
